# How to make a divs width equal to its height

Tags: jquery, css, html, geometry

I am building a responsive website which means I cannot deal in fixed widths and heights. In theory, the container should be 60% the width of the page and the height must match that. The question: how do i maintain the same width and height on a responsive page.

```
    <div id="container">
      <div id="circle">
      </div>
    </div>

#container {
   height:400px; width: 400px;
   padding:1%;
}
#circle {
   background-color:blue;
   border-radius:50%;
   height:96%; width:96%;
   position:absolute;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bundaberg/9wj5G/)
Thanks

Comment: And the problem you're having is...?

Comment: I am building a responsive website which means I cannot deal in fixed widths and heights. In theory, the container should be 60% the width of the page and the height must match that. 
The question: how do i maintain the same width and height on a responsive page. Apologies for not making that clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now i understand your problem.

**Use this CSS**

```
#container {
   padding-bottom:100%;
   position:relative;
   width: 60%;
   height: 100%;
}
#circle {
   background-color:blue;
   border-radius:50%;
   width:96%;
   padding-bottom:100%;
   position:absolute;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9wj5G/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your input but that is not the problem. I clarified the question with my reply to 'j08691', thanks

Comment: see the answer again, i did a remake @user2950370

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the optimal way, but here is an example using jQuery to set the width to the height of the div on window resize. [Here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/spaceagecrystal/4UtwH/5/)

```
$(window).resize(function() {
$('#container').width($('#container').height());
});
```